# Can't remove markers - Ionic cordova google maps plugin

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

[image]

I'm pushing markers to this array 'temp1' shown in the console, but I cant use .remove() function. I tested .getPosition() and .getId() functions and they worked.

Same problem with map.clear();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've raised an issue in ionic-native-google-maps github repository and they solved it.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/issues/3

The problem was one conditional in version 4.6.1, now the correct version is 4.6.3

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue with the plugin, I assume you are using plugin version 2.2.9, You need to downgrade to previous 2.2.8 and it will work again.

Comment: Just tried using 2.2.8 and it shows the same error, what version of "ionic-native/google-maps" should I use?

Comment: make sure you clear the plugins/platform folder. I had the same issue. Also make sure your package.json is locked to that specific version.